# How to identify the next number to complete the table?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, game-theory, operations-research, pattern-recognition

Consider the following table

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|lcr}
&the&A.J.& team &the &G.N.&team \\
\hline
 & 1 & 2 & John & 1 &2& Mark \\
\hline
Butterfly & 5 & 3 & 1&6&4&2 \\
Backstroke & 6 & 5 & 2&4&3&1 \\
Breaststroke & 5 & 4 &1 &6&3&2 
\end{array}

And this one

\begin{array}{c|c|c|lcr}
 & \text{Butterfly} & \text{Backstroke} & \text{Breaststroke} \\
\hline
Butterfly & 1 & -1 &  \\
Backstroke &  & &  \\
Breaststroke &  &  & 
\end{array}

- Where 1 came from:

(I think in these 3 equations Mark and John participate doing all styles)

1. 6-3=3    (As both participated, John won 5 points,Mark won 3 points and '2 swimmer' won 1 point, hence 5+1=6 less 3 because this is from the oponent team)
2. 3-6=-3
3. 5-4=1

Then 3-3+1=1

- And -1 came from

  1. 3-6=-3 (I think this was because John did not participate and Mark did)
  2. 5-4=1 (I think this was because John did participate and Mark didn't)
  3. 5-4=1 (I think this was because John and Mark participated both)

Then -3+1+1=-1

> Knowing this information and the points given (see the statement below) what should be the next number in the same row?

And then  in the rest of the table?

---

(The original problem started with this: The A. J. Swim Team soon will have an important swim
meet with the G. N. Swim Team. Each team has a star swimmer
(John and Mark, respectively) who can swim very well in the 100-
yard butterfly, backstroke, and breaststroke events. However, the
rules prevent them from being used in more than two of these
events.

Therefore, their coaches now need to decide how to use
them to maximum advantage.
Each team will enter three swimmers per event (the maximum
allowed). For each event, the following table gives the best time
previously achieved by John and Mark as well as the best time for
each of the other swimmers who will definitely enter that event.
(Whichever event John or Mark does not swim, his team’s third
entry for that event will be slower than the two shown in the table (first table).)

The points awarded are 5 points for first place, 3 points for
second place, 1 point for third place, and none for lower places.
Both coaches believe that all swimmers will essentially equal their
best times in this meet. Thus, John and Mark each will definitely
be entered in two of these three events.

Comment: As far as I understand, in the entry M,M both, Mark and John, participating in all styles. In the entry M,D first John does not participate and Mark does, then John does and Mark doesn't and finally Mark does and John does.

Comment: I don't understand where the $1$ came from.  You have several equations, but it is not clear to me where the numbers came from.  It looks like the coach has two decisions to make-which two events to use the star swimmer in, then which two to use swimmer 2 in, or are swimmers 1 and 2 permitted to swim all three races?

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry. I edited now

Answer (score 1):

Each coach has three strategies-which event to hold the star swimmer out of.  The second table should show the result of the meet based on the strategy each coach selects.  In the upper left, both stars sit out the butterfly, so the order of finish is AJ2, GN2, AJ3, which gives AJ six points for first and third and GN three points for second.  In the backstroke, GN places first and third and takes six points to AJ's three.  In the breaststroke AJ wins for five and GN takes second and third for four.  The overall match is $1$ point in AJ's favor, which is the $1$.

You can go through the table with this same approach.  Find the top three swimmers in each race given the participation or not of the stars.  See who wins the meet.  I assume the next question is what strategy each coach should follow.

Comment: What is denoting AJ2 ?

Comment: That's basically my question: to find the top three swimmers in each race given the participation or not of the stars. How will I know when are they going to participate or not? Knowing this the table can be computed. (See my first comment below my question)

Comment: The second swimmer on the AJ team, whose column is headed 2.  The 3 under his name in butterfly means that if neither star participates, he wins the event.

Comment: The row and column headings in the second table are the event the stars do not participate in.  In the first row, John does not swim the butterfly, in the second John does not swim the backstroke, in the first column Mark does not swim the butterfly and so on

Comment: I don't understand why you say _In the first row, John does not swim the butterfly, in the second John does not swim the backstroke, in the first column Mark does not swim the butterfly_ doing this does not match with my second equation  $5-4=1$, I get $-8+1=-7$ (where both Mark and John doesn't participate according to your comment).

Comment: Would you mind to more clear please?

Comment: In the first row, second column John does not swim the butterfly and Mark does not swim the backstroke.  The butterfly is then Mark, AJ2, GN2, which is $3-6=-3$.  The backstroke is John, GN2, GN1, for $5-4=1$.  The breaststroke is John, Mark, GN2, for $5-=14$ and overall AJ loses because $-3+1+1=-1$